# Aws Elastic Cache (Redis) failed to connect (jedis connection error) when acessed locally through spring boot java

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticache

I am working on a spring boot application where I have to store OTP in Elastic cache (Redis).

> Is elastic cache right choice to store OTP?

**Using Redis to store OTP**

To connect to Redis locally I used "**sudo apt-get install Redis-server**". It installed and successfully run.

I created a Redisconfig where I asked the application config file for port and hostname. Here I thought I will use this hostname and port to connect to aws elastic cache but Right now I am running locally.

```
public class RedisConfig {

@Value("${redis.hostname}")
private String redisHostName;

@Value("${redis.port}")
private int redisPort;

@Bean
protected JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
    return new JedisConnectionFactory();
}

@Bean
public RedisTemplate<String,Integer> redisTemplate() {
    final RedisTemplate<String, Integer> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
    return redisTemplate;
}
```

Now I used the RedisTemplate and valueOperation to put, read the data in Redis cache

```
public class MyService {

    private RedisTemplate<String, Integer> redisTemplate;

    private ValueOperations<String, Integer> valueOperations;

    public OtpService(RedisTemplate<String, Integer> redisTemplate) {
        super();
        this.redisTemplate = redisTemplate;
        valueOperations = redisTemplate.opsForValue();
    }

    public int generateOTP(String key) throws Exception {
        try {
            Random random = new Random();
            int otp = 1000 + random.nextInt(9000);
            valueOperations.set(key, otp, 120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            return otp;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("Exception while setting otp" + e.getMessage()) ;
        }
    }

    public int getOtp(String key) {
        try {
            return  valueOperations.get(key);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Now This is what I have done and which is running perfectly in local.

**Questions I have :**

1. What changes do I need when I am deploying the application in EC2 instance. Do we need to configure hostname and port in the code?
2. If we need to configure, Is there a way to test locally what would happen when we deploy? Can we simulate that environment somehow?
3. I have read that to access aws elastic cache (Redis) locally we have to set up proxy server, which is not a good practice, so how can we easily build the app locally and deploy on the cloud?
4. Why did ValueOperations don't have "delete" method when it has set, put methods? How can I invalidate cache once its usage is done before the expiry time?

**Accessing the AWS cache locally:**

When I tried to access the aws elastic cache (Redis) by putting the post and hostname in the creation of **JedisConnectionFactory** instance

```
    @Bean
    protected JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration configuration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(redisHostName, redisPort);
        JedisConnectionFactory factory = new JedisConnectionFactory(configuration);
        return factory;
    }
```

I got an error while setting the key value:

> Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is
>   redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get
>   a resource from the pool

I tried to explain what I have done and what I needed to know?
If anybody knows any blog, resources where things are mentioned in detail please direct me there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting the question, I tried things myself.

**As per amazon,**

> Your Amazon ElastiCache instances are designed to be accessed through
>   an Amazon EC2 instance.

```
To connect to Redis locally on Linux, 

Run "sudo apt-get install Redis-server". It will install redis server.
Run "redis-cli". It will run Redis on localhost:6379 successfully run.
```

To connect to server in java(spring boot)

**Redisconfig**

> **For local in application.properties**: redis.hostname = localhost, redis.port = 6379
>
> **For cloud or when deployed to ec2:** redis.hostname = "amazon Elastic cache endpoint", redis.port = 6379

```
public class RedisConfig {

@Value("${redis.hostname}")
private String redisHostName;

@Value("${redis.port}")
private int redisPort;

@Bean
protected JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
    RedisStandaloneConfiguration configuration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(redisHostName, redisPort);
    JedisConnectionFactory factory = new JedisConnectionFactory(configuration);
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public RedisTemplate<String,Integer> redisTemplate() {
    final RedisTemplate<String, Integer> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
    return redisTemplate;
}
```

With this whether you are running locally or on cloud just need to change the URL and things will work perfectly.

After this use RedisTemplate and valueOperation to put, read the data in Redis cache. Same as I mentioned in the question above. No need for any changes.

**Answers to the questions:**

1. We need to change the hostname when deploying in the EC2 instance.
2. Running Redis server locally is exactly same as running Redis when the application is deployed on EC2, no need for changes, use the Redis config I am using.
3. Yes, don't create a proxy server, this beats the very idea of the cache. run locally with Redis server and change hostname
4. I still need to find a way to invalidate the cache when using **valueOperations**